# How to convert to percentage

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Please help me how to convert this cell on Excel from number to percent

> the account: Banks - Global **0.308123555052582** --Internet Content &
>   Information **0.307825851134657** --Consumer Electronics
>   **0.383936697049749**

to become

> the account: Banks - Global **30.81%** --Internet Content &
>   Information **30.78%** --Consumer Electronics **38.39%**

Thank you.

Comment: I need to have formula to convert it. Thanks

Comment: I have ton of cells like this that need formula to convert rather than manual change each number by hand

Comment: I know some use substitute function but not sure how to use it

Comment: Hello Big Ben , try this on excel on cell A1 and format  as percentage

Comment: not just number, use exact phrase . Thx

Comment: Ahhhh. Your question made it sound like you had text in one cell and numbers in another, not text and numbers together. Maybe edit your question to explain that better.

Comment: Yes, I' m sorry, Not sure how to use edit. I'm not tech savvy.

Comment: they are all in one cell

Comment: can't you insert a column and to split to columns so that you'll have the numbers in a separate cell? If you need to you can concat them back together afterwards

Comment: I took a stab at editing the post - feel free to change it if that's not what you're looking for.

Comment: Thanks for the work, but I don't think It would work cause I have more than 100 cells phrases like this and I don't think I can break it like the way you do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps the following VBA solution using [Regular Expressions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22542835/9245853).

```
Function FixMyPercentages(target As String) As String
    Dim output As String
    output = target
    With New RegExp
        .Global = False
        .MultiLine = True
        .IgnoreCase = False
        .pattern = "\s\d+\.\d+$|^\d+\.\d+\s|\s\d+\.\d+\s"

        Dim myMatch As Object, myMatches As Object

        Do While .test(output)
            Set myMatches = .Execute(output)
            For Each myMatch In myMatches
                output = .Replace(output, " " & Format$(CDbl(myMatch.Value), "0.00%") & " ")
            Next myMatch
        Loop
    End With
    FixMyPercentages = Trim(output)
End Function
```

[image]

To implement this:

1. <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F11</kbd> to open the VB editor (or *Developer* > *Visual Basic*.)
2. Then *Insert* > *Module*
3. Paste the below code.
4. Add a reference to `Microsoft VBScript Regular Expressions 5.5` under *Tools* > *References*
5. And then use it as a formula in your worksheet.

[image]

Comment: Not sure how to use your work. Could you show me step by step. Many thanks.

Comment: Got error at With New RegExp

Comment: See the edit. You need to add the reference to `Microsoft VBScript Regular Expressions 5.5`.

Comment: Oh wow, it works terrific. If the phrase with ' abc .123, def .456, zxt .789 ' then will this vb function work or need to change on VB function? Many thanks again.

Comment: I got it. Thank you

Comment: Sorry , I just test with the phrase "  the account:   --Household & Personal Products 0.356331914717454 "  and the phrase " the account:   --Internet Content & Information 0.379707380917121 --Consumer Electronics 0.61217039828375 ". Both are not work. Do we need to change on VB function?

Comment: Getting rid of the space on the end should fix that.

Comment: Again, many may thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

@BigBen has a nice sophisticated solution. 
I'd probably do a 'dirty workaround', something like:

- In column A: find and replace a space followed by 0 by some divider ('|0')
- insert helper column B
- text to columns on column A, split on the divider put in place in step 1
- format the cells in column B to be %
- concatenate back together if needed.

Comment: Thanks for the work, but I don't think It would work cause I have more than 100 cells phrases like this and I don't think I can break it like the way you do